# Retire a SQL instance without impacting the primary server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 instance (`TST01`) that has some databases on it that are being migrated, still a few weeks of work to finish up, before the server is retired, this is a Virtual Server. There is also a separate instance on the server (TST01/ATST01) which is no longer required.

In theory I can run an uninstall and only uninstall the instance (TST01/ATST01). But I believe this will require a restart. As with any uninstall or update there is also some risk, and this is not worth any significant risk to the primary server.

I have off lined the user databases, disabled jobs, and maintenance plans.

This particular instance also has SSRS (built but never used) on it.

Is there anything else I can or should do?

The goal is to release as many resource to the VM pool, as practical, pending the full server retirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The goal is to release as many resource to the VM pool, as practical, pending the full server retirement.

You can just turn off sql server service of the instance that you are retiring and change the startup mode to disable.

Also, make sure to allocate the memory to other instance that is running form the decommissioned instance.

In a maintenance window, you can go ahead and uninstall SQL Server instance that you offlined.